# Create View query of 2 tables (with data from 3 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view, union

I want to make a query that combines 2 tables into a **view**. But to get all of the data that is required, I also have to query a third table (but this table does not have to appear in the view). It has to do simply the following (written in normal english):

Get **all records** from **edu_courses** (and remember the _id field)

THEN

Get **all records** from **edu_lessons** where **course_id** is equal to the **_id** fields from **edu_courses**

THEN

Get **all records** from **edu_lessons_dates** where **lesson_id** is equal to the **_id** field from **edu_lessons**

THEN

Search for the record in **edu_lessons_dates** with the closest `start_date` (if there are two equal `start_date` fields then it has to find the closest `start_time`)

EVENTUALLY

Combine the query to a single output (in a view or something) as:

```
'edu_courses_vw' ->

    edu_courses._id
       edu_courses.name
       edu_courses.content
       edu_courses.yt_url
       edu_courses.image_url
       edu_courses.difficulty_level
       edu_courses.price
       edu_courses.online (bool)
       edu_courses.max_people
       edu_lessons_dates.start_date
       edu_lessons_dates.start_time
```

I've tried the following, but this does not work at all:

```
select
courses._id,
courses.name,
courses.content, 
dates.start_date,
dates.end_date,
from
edu_courses courses
    join edu_lessons les
        on courses._id=les.course_id
    join edu_lessons_dates dates
        on les._id=dates.lesson_id

order by dates.start_date DESC, dates.start_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I have 3 tables with the following structure:

'edu_courses' ->

```
_id
   name
   content
   yt_url
   image_url
   difficulty_level
   price
   online (bool)
   max_people
```

'edu_lessons' ->

```
_id
   course_id
   name
   content
   sort
```

'edu_lessons_dates' ->

```
_id
   lesson_id
   start_date
   start_time
   end_date
   end_time
   current_people
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query (except that syntax error extra comma)?

Comment: I cannot see the end_date or end_time in my result. even when i select dates.start_date and dates.start_time in my query (See edit)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from
    edu_courses courses
        join edu_lessons les
            on cour' at line 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW edu_courses_vw AS
SELECT c._id
, c.name
, c.content
, c.yt_url
, c.image_url
, c.difficulty_level
, c.price
, c.online
, c.max_people
, d.start_date
FROM edu_courses c
JOIN edu_lessons l
    ON l.course_id = c._id
JOIN edu_lessons_dates d
    ON d.lesson_id = l._id
ORDER BY d.start_date DESC, d.start_time DESC
```

if you need only date of first lesson, you can use subquery like this:

```
SELECT c._id
, c.name
, c.content
, c.yt_url
, c.image_url
, c.difficulty_level
, c.price
, c.online
, c.max_people
, min_date_time
FROM edu_courses c
JOIN (SELECT MIN(d.start_date + d.start_time) AS min_date_time, l.course_id
  FROM edu_lessons l
  JOIN edu_lessons_dates d
    ON d.lesson_id = l._id
  GROUP BY l.course_id) AS ld ON ld.course_id = c._id
```

but it will be work correctly only if start_time it numeric time value (lesser then 1) or interval and start_date is date (datetime type). if this fields have other types you must convert it before sum.
EDIT:
for mysql:

```
SELECT c._id
, c.name
, c.content
, c.yt_url
, c.image_url
, c.difficulty_level
, c.price
, c.online
, c.max_people
, MIN(ADDTIME(d.start_date, d.start_time)) AS min_date_time
FROM edu_courses c
JOIN edu_lessons l
    ON l.course_id = c._id
JOIN edu_lessons_dates d
    ON d.lesson_id = l._id
GROUP BY c._id
, c.name
, c.content
, c.yt_url
, c.image_url
, c.difficulty_level
, c.price
, c.online
, c.max_people
```

you can also create view from subquery, and use it like table in query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW edu_courses_min_dt_vw AS
SELECT MIN(ADDTIME(d.start_date, d.start_time)) AS min_date_time, l.course_id
FROM edu_lessons l
JOIN edu_lessons_dates d
  ON d.lesson_id = l._id
GROUP BY l.course_id;

SELECT c._id
, c.name
, c.content
, c.yt_url
, c.image_url
, c.difficulty_level
, c.price
, c.online
, c.max_people
, min_date_time
FROM edu_courses c
LEFT JOIN edu_courses_min_dt_vw AS ld ON ld.course_id = c._id
```

Comment: Strange... #1054 - Unknown column 'edu_courses._id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I know for sure that the column is called _id in edu_courses

Comment: but error is for _id column, have you this field in edu_courses table? post result of SHOW COLUMNS FROM edu_courses;

Comment: Okay, your answer is almost correct. The view is created now, but i see as many courses as the courses have lessons. For example: if Course 1 has two lessons, then the View will show 2 times the course... I only want to see the course once, with the start_date of the first lesson in that course...

Comment: What data types you have on filed d.start_date & d.start_time in edu_lessons_dates table. Post example row.

Comment: My data types are: date and time... Date on my start_date column, and time on my start_time column

Comment: Thank you! I can convert your last edit into a VIEW and it works! However, the min_date_time is showing a weird value (20160405). I think that is the date, without the middle dash, AND without the time...

Comment: I use the Third query that you have posted but i Still got one question... When a course has NO LESSONS at all, the whole course is not displayed. However, I want that to display courses that contains no lessons but then set the `min_date_time` to NULL

Comment: You are my hero! ;) Thanks